# sql not showing proper result

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, group-by

I have following tables in mySql.

**blog**

```
Field       Type         
----------  ------------ 
id          int(11)
name        varchar(255)
user_id     int(11)
share       int(14)
```

**user_blog_analytics**

```
Field        Type        
-----------  ------------
id           int(11)
blog_id      int(11)
ip           varchar(255)
impressions  int(11)
date         date
```

**user_profile**

```
Field        Type        
-----------  ------------
id           int(11)
user_id      int(11)
description  text
share        int(14)
```

**user_profile_analytics**

```
Field        Type        
-----------  ------------
id           int(11)
user_id      int(11)
ip           varchar(255)
impressions  int(11)
date         date
```

**users**

```
Field        Type        
-----------  ------------
id           int(11)
email        varchar(255)
```

I want a query that gives me total blog shares of each users from `blog` table, total profile shares of each users from `user_profile` table, total blog views from yesterday i.e. from `user_blog_analytics` table, all time views on profile from `user_profile_analytics` table.

I created a query but not giving me the results I expect, it only gives me few results.

```
SELECT a.user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT b.ip) AS blog_view_count, a.share AS blog_share_count, c.share AS profile_share_count, COUNT(DISTINCT d.ip) AS user_profile_view
FROM blog AS a
JOIN user_blog_analytics AS b ON b.blog_id=a.id
JOIN user_profile AS c ON c.user_id=a.user_id
JOIN user_profile_analytics AS d ON d.user_id=c.user_id
JOIN users AS e ON e.id=a.user_id
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) = b.date AND e.role_id=2
GROUP BY a.id;
```

When I ran this query it gives me only one result but when I manually checked the tables then it should be giving me at least 2 results. Tell me where I am wrong and how can I get the result by modifying this query.

Comment: This is hard to tell without the data, but you have a few aggregate pieces in there. Can you share the results you get, and the results you expect? That might be enough data to tell what's going on.

Comment: So a user can have multiple profiles? And what is INT(14)? !?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.email, b.blog_share_count, b.blog_view_count, 
       up.profile_share_count, upa.user_profile_view
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.user_id, SUM(b.share) AS blog_share_count, COUNT(DISTINCT b.ip) AS blog_view_count
           FROM blog b 
           LEFT JOIN user_blog_analytics AS uba ON uba.blog_id = b.id AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) = uba.date
           GROUP BY b.user_id
         ) b ON u.id = b.user_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT up.user_id, SUM(up.share) AS profile_share_count 
           FROM user_profile up 
           GROUP BY up.user_id
         ) up ON u.id = up.user_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT up.user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT up.ip) AS user_profile_view 
           FROM user_profile_analytics up 
           GROUP BY up.user_id
         ) upa ON u.id = upa.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but something to think about...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table(i14 INT(14),i4 INT(4));

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (123456789012345,123456789012345);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+------------+------------+
| i14        | i4         |
+------------+------------+
| 2147483647 | 2147483647 |
+------------+------------+
```

So, the numbers in parentheses ain't doing much for ya!